# Number of Partitions vs Producer Throughput in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Does number of partitions have an impact on producer throughput in Kafka? 
( I understand that number of partitions is the upper bound for degree of parallelism on consumer side, but does it affect the producer performance ? )

I used the producer performance tool in Kafka to test this on a Kafka cluster setup on AWS. I observed that for 3 , 6 and 20 partitions the aggregated throughput in the cluster was approximately similar ( around 200 MB/s ). I would appreciate if you could help me clarify this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Were you running 1 producer per partition or just scaling up partitions and still running a single producer? What ack mode (0,1, or all)? What replication factor? There are so many variables with producers but 200 MB/sec on AWS with replication factor 3 and acks=all sounds a bit high. That's ~200,000 msg/sec of 1KB size messages.

Comment: I was using asynchronous replication ( acks =1 ), and used 3 producers on 3 different machines. ( 200MB/s is the aggregated throughput ). I did not run a producer per partition. I used the default settings for compression ratio and batch-size and other parameters. Replication factor was 2. Thank you.

Comment: If replication factor is 2 then each input stream is hitting 2/3rds of your clusters disk I/O capacity. Not a lot of room for much parallelism of writes. Also if replication is on the same subnet as client traffic then that's 400 MB/sec of total network bandwidth (or 3.2 Gbps) so you are getting some good results for a minimal 3 node cluster and 3 producers in AWS.

Answer (score 1):

an answer in two parts:

1. From the Kafka consumer perspective. Yes, partitions give improved throughput for Kafka consumers. But, I found that you really want to minimise the number of Kafka consumers (and therefore partitions) if you want good scalability. [Here's a link to a blog](https://www.instaclustr.com/apache-kafka-kongo-6-3-production-kafka-application-scalng-on-instaclustr/) I wrote last year on a Kafka IoT application (see section 2.3)
2. From the Kafka producer perspective, throughput drops with more partitions. Last week I ran some benchmarks with Kafka producers and different numbers of partitions and found that the throughput drops off significantly with more partitions. To "size" a Kafka cluster correctly, the only solution is to increase the Kafka cluster size (nodes and/or cores) until you get the target capacity with the required number of partitions. I needed 2M write/s and 200 partitions (for concurrency on the consumer side). For a 6 node (4 cores per node) cluster I could do 2.1M write/s with 6 partitions, but only 1.2M write/s with 200 partitions. On a 6 node cluster with 8 core nodes I could get 4.6M write/s with 6 partitions, and slightly more than my target throughput of 2.4M write/s with 200 partitions. I haven't blogged about these results yet but here's a link to the current blog series ([Anomalia Machina](https://www.instaclustr.com/anomalia-machina-1-massively-scalable-anomaly-detection-with-apache-kafka-and-cassandra/)).

Note: Throughput can also be increased by (a) reducing the replication factor or (b) by only writing to a subset of partitions (!) but then you probably don't need all the partitions.